# What are the differences between IOHK, Emurgo and the Cardano Foundation?

Tags: cardano-foundation, emurgo, iohk

What are the similarities and differences between IOHK, Emurgo and the Cardano Foundation? How do they independently provide value to the ecosystem? What are their individual mandates? Do they oversee each other in any way?

Answer (score 1):

IOHK is one of the world's pre-eminent blockchain infrastructure research and engineering companies.
The company builds high-assurance blockchain infrastructure solutions for public, private sector and government clients

EMURGO is a global blockchain technology company providing solutions for developers, startups, enterprises, and governments.
The Company develops, supports, and incubates commercial ventures and help integrate these businesses into cardano decentralized blockchain ecosystem. EMURGO also provides technical support services.

Cardano is a third-generation, decentralized proof-of-stake (PoS) blockchain platform designed to be a more efficient alternative to proof-of-work (PoW) networks. Scalability, interoperability, and sustainability on PoW networks like Ethereum are limited by the infrastructure burden of growing costs, energy use, and slow transaction times.
The Cardano platform runs on the Ouroboros consensus protocol. Ouroboros, created by Cardano in its foundation phase, is the first PoS protocol that not only was proved to be secure, but also was the first to be informed by scholarly academic research.